# Java - How to access highlighted material in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, copy-paste, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea and I have a menu which allows you to cut, copy and paste information through the `cut()`, `copy()` and `paste()` methods. However, I want these methods to get the highlighted text from the text area and use that in the methods. Is this possible and how would you go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JTextArea.getSelectedText()`

Comment: That is simpler than what I proposed :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HighLighter` + `DocumentListener` as described in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use the default Actions provided by the editor kit:

```
JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem( new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction() ) );
```